# extjs grid and chart

Tags: extjs, charts, local-storage

does someone knows how to use the same store for chart and for grid
actualy, the question is how to draw a bar chart representing prices for product category in this example

```
     http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/extjs-local-storage-example.html
```

code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>ExtJs 4 Local Storage Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="extjs-4.0.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs-4.0.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="myExample"></div>
 </body>
 </html>

 Ext.Loader.setConfig({ 
 enabled: true
  });

  Ext.application({

    name: 'myApp',
    appFolder: 'app',

     controllers: [
              'ItemMaster'
          ],
```

//data container

```
    launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
     renderTo: 'myExample',
     height: 250,
        width: 500,
        margin: '5 5 5 5 ',
     layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
             xtype: 'itemList'
            }
        ]
    });
  }
});
```

// model

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.Product', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
      'itemNumber',
      'description',
      'category',
      'price',
      ]
 });
```

// store

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.Products', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'myApp.model.Product',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
     type: 'localstorage',
    id  : 'myProxyKey'
}

});
```

//view

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.ItemList' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias : 'widget.itemList',
title : 'List of my Store Products',
store : 'Products',
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    store : 'Products',  
    dock: 'bottom',
    displayInfo: true,
    items: [
            { 
             xtype: 'tbseparator'
            },
            {
                xtype : 'button',
                text: 'Add Product',
                action: 'add'
      }
    ]
}],

initComponent: function() {

 this.columns = [
        {
         header: 'Item Number',  
         dataIndex: 'itemNumber',  
         flex: 1
        },
        {
         header: 'Description', 
         dataIndex: 'description', 
         flex: 2
        },
        {
         header: 'Category',  
         dataIndex: 'category',  
         flex: 1
        },
        {
         header: 'Price', 
         dataIndex: 'price', 
         flex: 1
        }
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
   }
   });
```

// form for adding and editing

```
 Ext.define('myApp.view.ItemEdit', {
 extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
 alias : 'widget.itemEdit',

 title : 'Product Maintenance',
 layout: 'fit',
 autoShow: true,

 initComponent: function() {
    this.items = [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'itemNumber',
                    fieldLabel: 'Item Number',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    msgTarget: 'side'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name : 'description',
                    fieldLabel: 'Description',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    msgTarget: 'side'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    name : 'category',
                    fieldLabel: 'Select Category',
                    store: ["Electronics","Software","Gaming"],
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    value: 'Electronics'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Price',
                    minValue: 0.01,
                    maxValue: 99.99,
                    value: 9.99,
                    name: 'price'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    this.buttons = [
        {
            text: 'Save',
            action: 'save'
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            scope: this,
            handler: this.close
        }
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
    }
   });
```

//controller

```
   Ext.define('myApp.controller.ItemMaster', {
   extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

   stores : ['Products'],
   models : ['Product'],
   views : ['ItemList', 'ItemEdit'],

   init : function() {
   this.control({
   'container > panel' : {
    render : this.onPanelRendered
   },
   'itemList' : {
    itemdblclick : this.editItem
   },
   'itemList button[action=add]' : {
    click : this.addItem
   },
   'itemEdit button[action=save]' : {
    click : this.updateItem
   }
  });
  },

 onPanelRendered : function() {
 //console.log('The panel was rendered');
 },

  editItem : function(grid, record) {
  var view = Ext.widget('itemEdit');
  view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
 },

 updateItem : function(button) {
  var win = button.up('window');
  var form = win.down('form').getForm();
 //check of the form has any errors
 if (form.isValid()) {
 //get the record 
 var record = form.getRecord();
 //get the form values
 var values = form.getValues();
 //if a new record
 if(!record){
  var newRecord = new myApp.model.Product(values);
  this.getProductsStore().add(newRecord);
 }
 //existing record
 else {
  record.set(values);
 }
 win.close();
 //save the data to the Web local Storage
 this.getProductsStore().sync();
}
},

addItem : function(button) {
var view = Ext.widget('itemEdit');
 }
});
```

thanks

Comment: What is the problem? Can't help if you don't explain what's not working

Comment: this is a working example. all i need is to make a chart using data from that grid

Comment: Please link to your working example, I can look into it if I can see it working, I'm not going to investigate your code running it in my head.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bucg7/1/  try this...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the same store, all you need to do is specify the same store for the chart

```
{xtype: 'chart', store: 'Products', ...}
```

**Working example** http://jsfiddle.net/bucg7/5/

You also should understand that a store is being magically created in the background by ExtJS, and it's being assigned the global id of 'Products'.

Notice that the chart rerenders as you sort your grid. If you don't want that behavior, you need two separate stores, where the store for the chart listens to changes from the grid.

Comment: in this example we fill the grid from form and save data to localStorage. now all i need is how to draw a chart using that dynamically added data. i am new at extjs so i would appreciate a litle help about this. thanks